# {- Re-Export -} in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I can't find anything about this:

```
module MyModule
    ( method1
    , method2

    {- Re-Export -} -- what's this?
    , method3(..)
    ) where
```

What's `{- Re-Export -}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a comment. It has no special significance. Haskell uses `--` to begin single-line comments and `{- -}` to surround multi-line comments. GHC has [pragmas](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/pragmas.html) for providing special instructions to the compiler, but they take the form `{-# word ... #-}` (note the `#`).

As an aside, imported modules *can* be re-exported:

```
module Foo
  ( foo
  , module Bar
  ) where

import Bar

foo = "foo"
```

will export both `foo` and the contents of `Bar`.

Comment: Correct, you can not dictate how a consuming module qualifies things.